# docker container + java application -> swap used -> why?

Tags: linux, docker, swap, containers

There is docker container with java application inside.

> docker inspect dbc237493367 | grep -P '((Memory)|(Pid))'

```
"Pid": 16283,
"PidMode": "",
"Memory": 10737418240,
"KernelMemory": 0,
"MemoryReservation": 0,
"MemorySwap": -1,
"MemorySwappiness": -1,
"PidsLimit": 0,
```

> ps auxw | grep 16283

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Xms9000m -Xmx9000m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m ...
```

> cat /proc/16283/status | grep -i vm

```
VmPeak: 20807456 kB
VmSize: 19735624 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:   6967836 kB
VmRSS:   3356220 kB
VmData: 19661552 kB
VmStk:       140 kB
VmExe:         4 kB
VmLib:     17964 kB
VmPTE:     24956 kB
VmPMD:        92 kB
VmSwap:  6283192 kB
```

> docker --version

```
Docker version 1.12.2, build bb80604
```

So:
1) docker container max memory set to 10gb
2) java application max memory set to 9gb
3) VmSwap value is 6gb ...

Question:
**how can that be possible? Why swap memory is used?**

Comment: It is by the way a bit snug to put a 9GB Heap in a 10GB memory. JVM needs some overhead, especially if you use many threads, lots of direct buffers or large applications with high usage in metaspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tips people wrote here.

So, i did 2 things:
1) increased container memory cause -Xmx does not include memory needed for threads ( threads count * stack size ), and my application use thousands of threads
2) changed "docker run" memory options from "--memory 10G" to "--memory 10G --memory-swap=10G --memory-swappiness=0"

So, now i expect swap no more to be used.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux kernel has a value called `swappiness`, which tells it how much of the memory to use before it starts using swap. By default it is usually somewhere around 60%, so it doesn't wait to use all of your memory before putting stuff in swap. That's probably a good idea; it takes time to put switch stuff to swap. The kernel leaves extra memory when it can to save itself that time.

There's more info on why it's like that in [this questioon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88693/why-is-swappiness-set-to-60-by-default)

EDIT: Any idea where the -1 swappiness is coming from? I'm curious, I've never seen that before. Have you tried setting it to 0?

Comment: Here is some background on swappiness with docker (I am however not sure why the original question shows swappiness=-1 on the inspect result, maybe this means inherit?): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767224/change-swappiness-for-docker-container